# How would I implement my own Rails-style validates() method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, mixins

I'm trying to understand some Ruby metaprogramming concepts.

I think I understand classes, objects, and metaclasses. Unfortunately, I'm very unclear on ***exactly what happens with included Modules with respect to their instance/'class' variables***.

Here's a contrived question whose solution will answer my questions:

***Suppose I'm writing my own crappy Rails "validates" method, but I want it to come from a mixed-in module, not a base class***:

```
module MyMixin
  # Somehow validates_wordiness_of() is defined/injected here.

  def valid?
    # Run through all of the fields enumerated in a class that uses
    # "validate_wordiness_of" and make sure they .match(/\A\w+\z/)
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyMixin

  # Now I can call this method in my class definition and it will
  # validate the word-ness of my string fields.
  validate_wordiness_of :string_field1, :string_field2, :string_field3

  # Insert rest of class here...
end

# This should work.
MyMixin.new.valid?
```

Ok, so how would you store that list of fields from the validate_wordiness_of invocation (in MyClass) in such a way that it can be used in the valid? method (from MyMixin)?

Or am I coming at this all wrong? Any info would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are two alternative ways of doing it:

**With "direct" access**

```
module MyMixin

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  def wordy?(value)
    value.length > 2
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def validates_wordiness_of(*attrs)
      define_method(:valid?) do
        attrs.all? do |attr|
          wordy?(send(attr))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyMixin

  validates_wordiness_of :foo, :bar

  def foo
    "a"
  end

  def bar
    "asrtioenarst"
  end
end

puts MyClass.new.valid?
```

The **downside** to this approach is that several consecutive calls to `validates_wordiness_of` will overwrite each other.

So you can't do this:

```
validates_wordiness_of :foo
validates_wordiness_of :bar
```

**Saving validated attribute names in the class**

You could also do this:

```
require 'set'
module MyMixin
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module Validation
    def valid?
      self.class.wordy_attributes.all? do |attr|
        wordy?(self.send(attr))
      end
    end

    def wordy?(value)
      value.length > 2
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def wordy_attributes
      @wordy_attributes ||= Set.new
    end

    def validates_wordiness_of(*attrs)
      include(Validation) unless validation_included?
      wordy_attributes.merge(attrs)
    end

    def validation_included?
      ancestors.include?(Validation)
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyMixin

  validates_wordiness_of :foo, :bar

  def foo
    "aastrarst"
  end

  def bar
    "asrtioenarst"
  end
end

MyClass.new.valid?
# => true
```

I chose to make the `valid?` method unavailable until you actually add a validation. This may be unwise. You could probably just have it return true if there are no validations.

This solution will quickly become unwieldy if you introduce other kinds of validations. In that case I would start wrapping validations in validator objects.

Comment: Why _nested_ modules? Asking just to read what you had in your mind.. :)

Comment: I nested `ClassMethods` in `MyMixin` because the inner module would not make sense outside of the `MyMixin` module. It is an integral part of `MyMixin`, not to be used anywhere else. As I explained in my last edit, the `Validation` module was introduced to make it possible to add the `valid?` method only when validations are present.

Comment: makes sense and well written too. +1

Comment: Thanks for the code sample! Makes sense, but you managed to solve the contrived problem without getting at my key question: is there a way for an extended Module to share state ***directly*** with the class into which it was extended?

I.e., could this have been solved without the wordy_attributes method on ClassMethods?

Comment: @honktronic maybe you should have made that a bit more clear? Perhaps my latest edit is more akin to what you need?

Comment: Re-read your comment. There's some confusion here. We're using `include` and not `extend` to begin with. And I don't see what you mean by **directly**. The module's methods are part of the including class, the module has direct access to any methods in the including class. The `wordy_attributes` creates a class-variable in the including class. How is this not direct sharing of state?

Comment: I'm definitely not explaining myself well, am I? Sorry about that. I realize we're using include for MyMixin but you're then base.extend(ClassMethods). I had originally asked (in my question) about "include" but figured that out on my own and went straight to asking about the "extend" case without making that clear. And by "directly" I meant "through directly shared state" (as opposed to getter method), but thinking more about what is actually going on, that doesn't make any sense. Thanks for bearing with my confusion!

Comment: Perhaps you know this, however: what is ***really*** going on when you create "@@some_var" in a class definition (i.e., between "class Foo" and "end")? Where does that var go? One would think that it would be an instance variable of the class Foo (and therefore a "class" variable to an object of that class, e.g., Foo.new) but it doesn't seem to be implemented that way...

Comment: @honktronic Maybe I came across as bit too confrontational. You gave me some food for thought, gonna look more closely at class/instance variables.

Comment: @honktronic I dabbled a bit in class/class instance variables here: https://gist.github.com/jesjos/4d029da5294f79b789af